# How to determine with JavaScript that some element has certain empty attribute declared?

Tags: javascript

```
<div aria-selected="" class="variantButton">
```

When attribute is non empty I do this:

```
if (elem.getAttribute("aria-selected"))
    //do something
```

But this will not work in case of empty string.

P.S. I don't use jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`hasAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/hasAttribute):

```js
console.log( document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].hasAttribute("aria-selected") )
```

```html
<div aria-selected="" class="variantButton">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if (elem.getAttribute("aria-selected") && elem.getAttribute("aria-selected") !== "")
```

Comment: First statement is instant false, second would not even check.

Comment: [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) returns `null` or `""` for attributes that don't exist. That's why we have [`hasAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/hasAttribute).